# Angular-js ng-if issue in tables TD

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide a td, when getting a value = 0,
I typed

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in typeData"
<td ng-if="row.AMOUNTPAID >      0">@{{row.AMOUNTPAID}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The td is not hiding, I tried ng-show it works but ng-show works on the css, and an empty space still showing in the table with the td border.

I read about updating angular-js will fix the problem, i have 1.4.6 it has the ngif directive but not working.

Any help please ?

Comment: Do you have 1 column in table or multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see how your data object is defined, please find a possible solution beneath. I've made a sample, provided with some dummy data.

Also see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osj2fq52/1/)

The problem in your example is that the `tr` close tag is missing at :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in typeData"
```

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">  
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="row.amountpaid > 0">{{row.amountpaid}}</td>
        <td ng-if="row.amountpaid <= 0">NO PAYMENT YET</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// controller
myApp.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  // set data
  $scope.data = [{
    'name': 'bot1',
    'amountpaid': '145'
  }, {
    'name': 'bot2',
    'amountpaid': '10'
  }, {
    'name': 'bot3',
    'amountpaid': '5'
  }, {
    'name': 'bot4',
    'amountpaid': '0'
  }, {    
    'name': 'bot5',
    'amountpaid': '0'
  }];

})
```